# Keeping NaN values and dropping nonmissing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where I would like to keep the rows when a particular variable has a `NaN` value and drop the non-missing values.

Example:

```
ticker  opinion  x1       x2  
aapl    GC       100      70  
msft    NaN      50       40  
goog    GC       40       60  
wmt     GC       45       15  
abm     NaN      80       90
```

In the above DataFrame, I would like to drop all observations where opinion is not missing (so, I would like to drop the rows where ticker is `aapl, goog, and wmt`).

Is there anything in pandas that is the opposite to `.dropna()`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isnull.html) on the column to find the missing values and index with the result.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'ticker': ['aapl', 'msft', 'goog'],
                     'opinion': ['GC', nan, 'GC'],
                     'x1': [100, 50, 40]})

data = data[data['opinion'].isnull()]
```

Comment: Or `isna()`. `isnull` is just an alias for `isna` so either will work

Answer (score 4):

Not what the OP was asking, but in case you're here for the inverse of `df.dropna()`, the equivalent of `df.keepna()` would be:

```py
df[~df.index.isin(df.dropna().index)]
```

Comment: `df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]` will give the same results

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [4]: df.query('opinion != opinion')
Out[4]: 
  ticker opinion  x1  x2
1   msft     NaN  50  40
4    abm     NaN  80  90
```

This works as *NaN* is not equal to *NaN*:

```
In [5]: np.nan != np.nan
Out[5]: True
```