# Drop all rows that *do not* contain any NaNs in their columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I use to drop the rows which has one cell with NAN value with this command:

```
pos_data = df.iloc[:,[5,6,2]].dropna()
```

No I want to know how can I keep the rows with NAN and remove all other rows which do not have NAN in one of their columns.
my data is Pandas dataframe.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430995/keeping-nan-values-and-dropping-nonmissing-values

Comment: @hygorxaraujo Seems like that is just for one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use boolean indexing, find all columns that have at least *one* NaN in their rows and use the mask to filter.

```
df[df.iloc[:, [5, 6, 2]].isna().any(1)]
```

The DeMorgan equivalent of this is:

```
df[~df.iloc[:, [5, 6, 2]].notna().all(1)]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x', 'x', np.nan, np.nan], 'B': ['y', np.nan, 'y', 'y'], 'C': list('zzz') + [np.nan]})
df

     A    B    C
0    x    y    z
1    x  NaN    z
2  NaN    y    z
3  NaN    y  NaN
```

If we're only considering columns "A" and "C", then our solution will look like

```
df[['A', 'C']]

     A    C
0    x    z
1    x    z
2  NaN    z
3  NaN  NaN

# Check which cells are NaN
df[['A', 'C']].isna()

       A      C
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True  False
3   True   True

# Use `any` along the first axis to perform a logical OR across columns
df[['A', 'C']].isna().any(axis=1)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool

# Now, we filter
df[df[['A', 'C']].isna().any(axis=1)]

     A  B    C
2  NaN  y    z
3  NaN  y  NaN
```

As mentioned, the inverse of this is using `notna` + `all(axis=1)`:

```
df[['A', 'C']].notna().all(1)

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

# You'll notice this is the logical inverse of what we need, 
# so we invert using bitwise NOT `~` operator
~df[['A', 'C']].notna().all(1)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: could you please tell me the role of  any(), 1 , and ~?

Answer (score 0):

This should remove all rows that do no have at least 1 na value:

```
df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: It will look at _all_ columns before removing rows, not considering only columns 5, 6, and 2 (your answer is effectively mine, but not as correct)